# Creating a guessing game in Python using while and for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to make a guess game. I've used while, if, elif, and else statements but I'm stuck on how to use for and while loops as well as randomizing single hints and single answers from a nested lists.

```
black_box = ["guam","lakers","flash","buddha","drake","fortnite","annabelle","xmen","mars","dad"] 
nested_list = [["island","yigo","cocos","kelaguen"],["kobe","la","magic","lebron"],["scarlet","speedster","dc","ezra"], ["asiangod","meditation","monk","enlightenment"],["rapper","onedance","canadian","raptors"],["game","epic","notminecraft","dances"],["doll","conjuring","soultaker","creation"],["wolverine","mystique","magneto","apocalypse"],["red","fourth","planet","ares"], ["man","american","peter","lionking"]] 
i = random.randint(0,9) 
word = black_box[i] 
hint = nested_list[i] 
print("Guess the word with the following hint: ", hint, "you have 4 tries.") 
numofguesses = 0 
guess = input("What is the word? ") 
while numofguesses < 4: 
    numofguesses = numofguesses + 1 
    if guess == word: 
        print("You win!") 
option = input("Do you want to try again or quit? ") 
if option == "try again": 
    print("") 
elif option == "quit": 
    break 
if guess != word: 
    print("Try again!") 
    guess = input("What is the word? ") 
    if guess != word: 
        print("Try again!") 
        guess = input("What is the word? ")
```

I expected to get a line of code that prints "Try again!" but it skipped and started to print "What is the word? " print("Guess the word with the following hint: ", hint, "you have 4 tries.") Originally, I used hint[i] which printed out only one hint in the nested list but then I tried to run the program again but I got an error saying, "list index is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition checks and loops where not correct. Try the below code, it should work fine.

```
black_box = ["guam","lakers","flash","buddha","drake","fortnite","annabelle","xmen","mars","dad"]
nested_list = [["island","yigo","cocos","kelaguen"],["kobe","la","magic","lebron"],["scarlet","speedster","dc","ezra"], ["asiangod","meditation","monk","enlightenment"],["rapper","onedance","canadian","raptors"],["game","epic","notminecraft","dances"],["doll","conjuring","soultaker","creation"],["wolverine","mystique","magneto","apocalypse"],["red","fourth","planet","ares"], ["man","american","peter","lionking"]]
while True:
    i = random.randint(0, 9)
    word = black_box[i]
    numofguesses = 0
    while numofguesses < 4:
        hint = nested_list[i][numofguesses]
        print("Guess the word with the following hint: ", hint, ". You have ", 4 - numofguesses, " tries!")
        guess = input("What is the word? ")
        numofguesses = numofguesses + 1
        if guess == word:
            print("You win!")
            break
        if guess != word:
            print("Try again!")
    option = input("Do you want to try again or quit? ")
    if option == "try again":
        print("")
    else:
        break
```